# How can I take the strings in a list and put them together in a variable? [Python]

Tags: python, list

```
word =("Enter a word: ")
listword = list(word)

def final():
    while True:
        index = int(input("Enter an index: "))
        if index > len(word) - 1:
           input print "Try again"
            continue
        else:
            break
    while True:
            letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
            if len(letter) == 1:
                break
            else:
                continue
    listword[index] = letter
    print listword
while True:
    final()
```

Comment: How can I take the letters in the list and print them as one string instead of separate in a list?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what you meant:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
listword = list(word)

while True:
    index = int(input("Enter an index: "))
    if index <= len(word) - 1:
        break
    print("Try again")

while True:
    letter = input("Enter a letter: ")
    if len(letter) == 1:
        break

listword[index] = letter
print("".join(listword))
```